# What is the difference between these codes that gives the same output?

Tags: jquery

Maybe I lack of information on reading just wandering why code has different way of style but same output?. Can someone explain it to me?.

For example like this

`$("#ID").val()` - `$('#ID').val()` --- The difference is the single and double quote.

`$("#ID").attr("disabled",true)` - `$('#ID').attr('disabled','disabled')` --- Same again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it does not matter to use single or double quotes in above. but in case like creating dynamic html as an example :

```
var create_element = $("<div class='myclass'></div>");
```

you have to use both.

for more details about `single` or `double` quotes  [refer this link](http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/#quotes)

for your second question, there isn't a difference of using `true` or `disabled`. but from `jQuery`1.6 and above`, should use`true`.

Comment: But it is also okay using the `disabled`?

Comment: I have mentioned in my answer `there isn't a difference of using true or disabled`  .yep, but the proper way is to use `true`.